# Optimal way of getting user roles in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I need to check user rights in my controller to decide which list of parameters are being sending to the view.
I know that I can check wheter particular user has particular roles by two ways:

1. **Method 1** - Create helper class with code below:
   *SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream()
                   .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(roleName));*
2. **Method 2** - add HttpServletRequest req to controller and then req.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")

But which way is the best? As for me, I take first one is more useful because I can use it outside the controller for internal purposes.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/goal/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit (@PathVariable Long id, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect, HttpServletRequest req) {
        Goal goal = goalService.getById(id);

        //Method 1 
        User user = AuthUtils.getCurrentUser();

        //Medhod 2
        Boolean is_admin = req.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN");

        Iterable<Role> roles = null;

        if (is_admin==true) {
            roles = roleService.getAll();
            }
            else roles = user.getRoles();

        model.addAttribute("goal", goal);
        model.addAttribute("roles", roles);
        return "goal_form";
    }
```

```
    public class AuthUtils {
    public static boolean hasRole (User user, String roleName)
        {
            return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream()
                    .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals(roleName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not about which one you prefer, which one you need!
do you need to check the user role outside the controllers if yes then you are right to use the first one but if you don't need it outside the controllers the second way is faster

Answer (score -1):

As [AMA's answers in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60632454/optimal-way-of-getting-user-roles-in-spring-security/60639761#comment107269897_60632454):

> It's not about which one you prefer, which one you need!
>   do you need to check the user role outside the controllers if yes then you are right to use the first one but if you don't need it outside the controllers the second way is faster

I need to check user role outside the controllers I will user first method.